# Calculate rank base on addition of score in mysql < version 8

Tags: mysql

[see image the dscription][1]
i have written query for calculate rank base on sum of score group by mobile number and i am getting rank result as
1,2,3,3,3,4

but i want my rank as 1,2,3,3,3,6 i know i can do it by simply RANK() function but my sql version is older and not support RANK()

My query is

```
select  id, total,name,
        CASE WHEN @l=total THEN @r ELSE @r:=@r+1 END as rank,
        @l:=total
FROM (
  select id,name, sum(score) as total
  from quiz_users
  group by mobile
  order by total desc
) totals, 
(SELECT @r:=0, @l:=NULL) rank


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHS1u.png
```

Comment: Are you really using Codeigniter and Laravel? Or are you spamming tags?

Comment: yes i am using codeigniter.

Comment: What application programming language or orm you use is irrelevant if your question is about sql only.

Answer (score 0):

Surely this is easier and does the right job, I think

```
SELECT    id, score, name,
          @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS `rank`
FROM      quiz_users q, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
ORDER BY  score;
```

Comment: according to your query it return rank like 1234 but i want rank like 123336 if my score is same it should be assign same rank if two user have same rank.